# SMTP connect() failed. suddenly

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

can you guys help me?
what's wrong with this code. already various ways I try but still SMTP connect () failed. initially email delivery succeeded, but I try to return the next day SMTP connect () failed this appears on my site.

```
require 'php-mailer/class.phpmailer.php';
require 'php-mailer/class.smtp.php';
require 'php-mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'name@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '********';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->From = 'example@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'example';

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->SetFrom('example@gmail.com', 'example');
$mail->AddReplyTo('example@gmail.com','example');

$mail->Subject = 'My Subject';
$mail->Body = 'Content Mail';
$mail->AltBody = '';

$mail->AddAddress('me@gmail.com', 'My Name');
//$mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');
//$mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif');
if(!$mail->send()){
    echo "<h2 style='color:#df0000'>Email not sent!.</h2>";
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
    echo "<h1>Success !!!</h1>";
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the error message you received (with `echo $mail->ErrorInfo`)?

Comment: I received an error message
`SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting`..
but it not helpful..

Comment: Not helpful in the sense that you couldn't be bothered to follow the link, read it, or do what it says to diagnose your problem? Nobody here is going to suggest anything that's not already in that doc. You're also using an old version of PHPMailer, and have based your code on an obsolete example that contains simple mistakes (for example `tsl` should be `tls`).

Comment: thank you is very helpful, and I apologize for my carelessness.
I tried the new PHPMailer but it looks different from the version I use. And in the example code wrote `require 'vendor / autoload.php';` but I did not find the file in PHPMailer folder, it makes me dizzy ..

Comment: Same problem here, there has been a wave of people being unable to send emails through gmail since late November.